# Paths in Kubernetes Ingress Specs

Tags: path, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have the following ingress resource for one of my apps

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name:""
    annotations:
      ingress.kubernetes.io..
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: my-app
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /path/to/service
          backend:
            serviceName: my-service
            servicePort: 80
```

This works as expected and I can access my service at `http://my-app/path/to/service`. However the service in my app takes query parameters that dont seem to correctly get redirected for eg:

```
http://my-app/path/to/service/more/paths
```

This brings me back to `http://my-app/path/to/service`

How can I maintain this path structure ?

Comment: what ingress controller do you use?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you need to use wildcards on your path:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name:""
    annotations:
      ingress.kubernetes.io..
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: my-app
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /path/to/service/*
          backend:
            serviceName: my-service
            servicePort: 80
```

More information [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120). Seems like it's hard to find any docs with wildcard examples. Not that this is specific to nginx, it may not work with other ingress controllers.

Comment: This is specific to nginx. I am using appgw and there is no wildcard support

Comment: Noted in the answer. Thx!